# Hiding the login credentials in header part in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have login credentials(Which is email and password) in header part. Which is included in all pages. After login how to hide that login credentials. I used Servlets code in JSP pages. I have only JSP pages, Anybody Please help me.

```
login.jsp
___________********_______

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn1").click(function(){
$("input").hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body  style="background-color: wheat;">
<div>Email<input class="span2" id="logInEmail" type="text">&nbsp; &nbsp;
   Password<input class="span2" id="logInPass" type="password"><br></div>
<a class="btn1" href="welcome.jsp">Sign in</a>
</body>
</html>
________************_____________

index.jsp
_________************____________
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="login.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is index page</p>
<p>This is for paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
____________************_________

welcome.jsp
_____________*************________
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="login.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Welcome success</h4>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>

 *******************
```

Comment: Without any code it's very hard for us to help you ;-)

Comment: are you using post request?

Comment: use post request rather than get

Comment: It would help if you actually had a form in your form page.

Answer (score 0):

Use method="post" in  and store the email in session in validation success block.

```
 if valid user
 HttpSession session=request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("email", emailid);
```

to get emailid in any page

```
String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email");
```